# formatting data in sql to a single row

Tags: sql

I have a sql which is returning the data like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
workitem_id,
case when state ='Created' then newimage_lastupdateddate else null end  as creation_date,
case when state ='Disconnected' then newimage_lastupdateddate else null end as disconnect_date
from work_item
```

| workitem_id | channel | creation_date | diconnect_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | task | 2021-10-02 08:37:24 | null |
| 123 | task | null | 2021-10-02 11:36:58 |

I want the data in 1 row as given below.

| workitem_id | channel | creation_date | diconnect_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | task | 2021-10-02 08:37:24 | 2021-10-02 11:36:58 |

How can I do it ?

Comment: Maybe also include your sql query which probably just needs some simple aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

The DISTINCT is generating the issue.

Try

```
SELECT D
workitem_id,
min(case when state ='Created' then newimage_lastupdateddate else null end ) as creation_date,
max(case when state ='Disconnected' then newimage_lastupdateddate else null end) as disconnect_date
from work_item 
group by workitem_id
```

not sure if min and max are the optimal for your data. In case you are not sure , please copy the data here .

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating and grouping by `workitem_id`

```
select workitem_id,
    Max(case when state ='Created' then newimage_lastupdateddate end) as creation_date,
    Max(case when state ='Disconnected' then newimage_lastupdateddate end) as disconnect_date
from work_item 
group by workitem_id
```